# matplotlib align ticks with end of scale

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

If I plot something in matplotlib it chooses the spacing on y-axis by itself (where it puts ticks). How can I tell the axes to always end with an full tick and not in between two ticks?

If it choses to make a tick every 0.5, that the end is 2.0 and not a little bit higher than 2.0 with no tick.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [0.1,0.3,2.4,3.9,3.2]

plt.plot(X, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: you can manually edit the ticklabels

Comment: matplotlib choses slightly over 4.0 as top, when i want it to end at 4.0. But i do not want to set it to 4.0 but it should be calculated by matplotlib what the value is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` if you want to restrict the limits to within some range. Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = [1,2,3,4,5]
# y = [0.1,0.3,2.4,3.9,3.2]
y = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,1.1]

plt.plot(X, y)
plt.xlim(min(X), max(X))
ticks = [tick for tick in ax.get_yticks()]
plt.ylim(ticks[0], ticks[-1])
# plt.ylim(np.floor(min(y)), np.ceil(max(y))) # If you want only integer upper and lower limits
```

EDIT: This addresses your concern for the following set of values `X = [1,2,3,4,5]` and  `y = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,1.1]`

[image]

Comment: i want the 4.0, but not the space above it.

Comment: Ok, then just add `plt.ylim(min(y), 4)`

Comment: yes but i want to without knowing 4, so i can use it for every picture.

Comment: In that case, use `plt.ylim(min(y), np.ceil(max(y)))`

Comment: and what is when the spacing, that matplotlib concluded,  are not integers?

Comment: My edited answer will make the upper and lower y limit as integers. I don't understand what you mean by spacing. Do you only want to display integer values as ticks. For example, just 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on?

Comment: X = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,1.1]
plt.margins(0, 0) then y_max should be 1.2 and not 2.0

Comment: @user3613886 FYI, If you are setting the limits using `plt.yticks()` you don't need to use `plt.margins()`

Comment: @user3613886: Check my edit now which answers your concern for `1.2`. Of course the answer will vary if you want only integers. That's why I have commented out 2 lines which are meant for integer values.

Answer (score 5):

By default you will get the axes autoscaled to extend by some percentage of the range of the data.

[image]

So the tick locations and the axis limits are totally uncorrelated. This mostly gives a nice visual appearance of the chart content.

You may however decide to activate the round number autolimit mode,

```
plt.rcParams['axes.autolimit_mode'] = 'round_numbers'
```

to have the limits and ticks correlate:

[image]

Here, a lot of whitespace is created around the plotted data. You may decide to set the margins to `0` to aviod that

```
plt.rcParams['axes.autolimit_mode'] = 'round_numbers'
plt.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0
plt.rcParams['axes.ymargin'] = 0
```

[image]

Note that this mode will in general expand to the next "nice number", which may, or may not be desired. E.g. if you let the first x value be a bit smaller than 1, `X = [0.99,2,3,4,5]` the limits will expand down to 0.5

[image]

There is also an [example available](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/auto_ticks.html) on the matplotlib page.

Answer (score 1):

The newer versions of matplotlib now add margins to your plot by default. You can remove them by calling `plt.margins(0, 0)`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [0.1,0.3,2.4,3.9,3.2]

plt.plot(X, y)
plt.margins(0, 0)
plt.show()
```

This does however generate the axes limts automatically. In the above example, this will not include 0 or 4 (because the data does not include 0 or 4). Therefore, you can set the axes limits yourself:

```
plt.ylim(0, 4)
```

Comment: if i use margins = 0,0.  why does he remove the top label?

Comment: @user3613886 Because matplotlib will automatically generate the limits. If you know what limits you want you can set them yourself. I've edited my answer with how to do that and some explanation.

Comment: and how can i use the spacing that matplotlib concluded and use it auto set to 0 and 4, without explicitly using that i know it is 4 and 0?

Comment: See the edit to Bazingaa's answer to set the limits to the nearest integer